# Why do parameter tab-autocomplete results show provider (e.g. filesystem) objects by default?

Tags: powershell, psreadline

You can define auto-completion results for parameter values in a variety of different ways such as using dynamic parameters, the [CompletionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.completionresult?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) class within a parameter's [ArgumentCompleter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_argument_completion?view=powershell-7.3#argumentcompleter-attribute) attribute declaration, the [ValidateSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validateset-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.3) attribute, etc.

If tab-completion results aren't declared, then PowerShell (by default) will return a contextual list of provider objects/items for parameter value auto-completion suggestions (whether "autocompleted" with `Tab` or `CTRL+SPACE`).

For example, pressing `CTRL+SPACE` after `Test -ParamName` shows a list of filesystem objects.

[image]

---

I know that `CTRL+SPACE` is PSReadLine's [MenuComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-keyhandlers?view=powershell-7.3#menucomplete) function at work, but even if PSReadLine is removed, the default behavior of returning contextual provider objects still persists when using `Tab` to autocomplete parameter values.

Is this default behavior/preference (of returning provider objects) exposed anywhere like an automatic variable, .NET class property/field, .ps1xml file, etc?

Comment: this is the default behavior of `tabexpansion2`, more specifically `[System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput` when there are no completion results it will default to the child items in the current location

Comment: Thank you Santiago!  If you put this into an answer I'll mark it as such.  Thanks again :)

Comment: heh unfortunately the question is closed. i've voted to reopen it but there needs to be 3 votes for that to happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the [`TabExpansion2` built-in function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_tab_expansion?view=powershell-7.3), more specifically, it is the default behavior of [`CommandCompletion.CompleteInput` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandcompletion.completeinput?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) when there are no completion results it will default to the child items in the current location:

```bash
function Test-Completion {param($Param) }
# This is the simulated input:
$statement = 'Test-Completion '

# Should output the child items in the current location:
[System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
    $statement, $statement.Length, $null).
    CompletionMatches
```

If you would like to check the definition of your `TabExpansion2` function / override its default behavior you can use:

```
(Get-Command TabExpansion2).Definition
```